# How to run the test classes in particular order using SeleniumWebDriver(Java) with TestNG?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to run the Selenium WebDriver (Java) test classes in the particular order using TestNG.

For eg. I have 3 classes such as Test1, Test2 and Test3. I want to run in the order Test2, Test1 and Test3. Is it possible without grouping?

I tried the following way, but I runs in its own order (Alphabetical order).

```
<suite name="MyTestSuite" verbose="4">

<test name="MyTest">
   <classes>
        <class name="com.mypackage.Test2" />
        <class name="com.mypackage.Test1" />
        <class name="com.mypackage.Test3" />
   </classes>
</test>
```

Is there any other way to do this? Without grouping is this possible?

Comment: What version of Testng r u on?

Comment: TestNG version is 5.11. Will it work in 6.7?

Comment: Yes..this works in higher versions.  As per change log the first occurence I see is in 5.14.

Comment: Sorry man Now I have upgraded TestNG to 5.14. Still not working.

Comment: That was when it was introduced.  Well I have 6.2.1, works with that for sure.  Also are you using the plugin version or ur project jar?

Comment: Thanks niharika_neo. Its working in TestNG 6.7. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use *preserve-order="true"* to make classes to run in given order.

```
<suite name="MyTestSuite" verbose="4">

<test name="MyTest" >
   <classes preserve-order="true">
        <class name="com.mypackage.Test2" />
        <class name="com.mypackage.Test1" />
        <class name="com.mypackage.Test3" />
   </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: Santhosh, Still it runs in its own order. Also i tried <test name="MyTest" preserve-order="true">. This also not working

Comment: Santhosh thanks it is working in TestNG 6.7. Earlier I used 5.11. Good answer. i have accepted it.

Comment: My pleasure to help you Prince. I was out of station 3 days that's why I didn't reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this test plan(.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
  <suite name="MyTestSuite" preserve-order="true">
     <test name="MyTest">
        <classes>
             <class name="com.mypackage.Test2"> </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="MyTest 1">
       <classes>
          <class name="com.mypackage.Test1"> </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="MyTest 2">
        <classes>
          <class name="com.mypackage.Test3"> </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```