# How to create a test suite that runs one test class at a time using TestNG

Tags: java, testng, test-suite

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Regression"  parallel="false" >
    <test name="1"  >
        <classes  >
            <!--<class name="Createnewform" />-->
            <class name="Preparer" />
            <!--<class name="n_CreateNewForm" />-->
            <!--<class name="eV_createNewForm" />-->
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="2" >
    <classes  >
        <class name="R_createnewform" />
</classes>

    </test>
</suite>
```

Below is how I setup my XML. I want to be able to order my test classes here and run it in that order. How do I do that? I done a lot of research but have not found a solution. I am using TestNG so each of my classes has priority set but I do not want my test suite to care about the content of each test class, I just want it to run one test class at a time.

Comment: Somehow it did not save. <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Regression"  parallel="false" >

Comment: Post the complete xml that you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run the test classes in particular order using SeleniumWebDriver(Java) with TestNG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954779/how-to-run-the-test-classes-in-particular-order-using-seleniumwebdriverjava-wi)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I tried that, the test suite still ran in parallel. thanks

Comment: @CharliynTran I rolled back your last change, if you remove the "four spaces" your code is not visible.

Comment: @CharliynTran which version you're using?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti  I'm using IntelliJ 14.1.15 and testng 6.7

Comment: @Shamik added thanks

Comment: How are you triggering your tests?  There's nothing wrong with the xml and the classes should have run sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

```
<suite name="Regression" preserve-order="true" parallel="false" >
```

use this it should work

You can add that flag at test level as well if you want the separate tests to run in any order.

For further information check [this](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) .

Comment: Remove the parallel tag. I t should work. Can you give the full exception

Comment: That's all of it, "This attribute does not belong here." and I removed the parallel tag, that didn't solve the issue

Comment: But this works for me. Kindly remove the parallel attribute and see what happens

Comment: I'm just going to remove the @Test (priority = 1) I set in each test class.. let me see if that works..

Comment: No it works with that. It works for me.I use this -<suite allow-return-values="false" configfailurepolicy="skip" data-provider-thread-count="10" group-by-instances="false" junit="false" name="FullSuite" parallel="false" preserve-order="true" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" thread-count="5" verbose="1">

Comment: I ran it without the parallel tag and it still ended up with two browsers :(

Comment: Hey you need to add them in your test tags as well. <test name="1"  preserve-order="true"  >

first one ensures that the <test> orders are maintained, second one ensures that the individual class orders are maintained

Comment: I think it might just me an issue with my test classes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please try out the above comment. I think putting them in test tag will do the trick

Comment: I figured it out, it's my test classes. I had a "get" command before a "@test" so somehow that initiates an additional browser for me for each test class. Thank you for your help, going through all the options helped me see the solution

Answer (score 0):

[Defining dependencies](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations) is an alternative functionality in TestNG to achieve ordered execution.